# Solidity Uniswap smartContract swap is getting cancelled

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

I've setup my own smart-contract for sushiswap and when trying to swap from WETH to DAI, the transaction succeed but I'm not getting any DAI, only the gas seems to be spent.

Here's my smart-contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Uniswap {
    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;
    address private constant WETH = 0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C;

    function swap(
        address _tokenIn,
        address _tokenOut,
        uint256 _amountIn
    ) external {
        IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
        IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;

        address recipient = address(this);

        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            0,
            path,
            recipient,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);


}
```

I made tests on two differents testnet : Ropsten & Kovan actually that's the same error happening.

It's seems that in the internal error there is two interractions with WETH like if the swap was canceled once it's finished.

And here's the TX:

Etherscan tx

[image: 1]

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: @ErimVarış I just edited the post with more details :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with increasing deadline which is last parameter of swapExactTokensForTokens

For ex add 5 to it. And try with that. If it wont work share the transaction hash with me to analyse better.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer, it didn't succeed when I tried to increase the deadline.

Here is my tx: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x51da62d2927171a02976cd39c2737b8c49499131928d70223f0ff25e5362b024

Here is a sucessfull tx on sushiswap contract:

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x54e1e03951d108353663111c2919541ee84a6fa35720f0725a930743f72d7933

Thanks for the help ! :) 

@ErimVarış